# Python - issuewith encoding when deploying to hosting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code: which writes some Russian symbols to csv file:

```
def start_csv_writer(self, result_file_name):
            scriptpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
            result_file_name = os.path.join(scriptpath, result_file_name)
            open(result_file_name, 'w',encoding='utf8').close()
            result = open(result_file_name, 'ab',encoding='utf8')
            csv_writer = csv.writer(result, delimiter=';', quotechar='"',lineterminator='\n')
            csv_writer.writerow(['запрос', '#', 'url', 'заголовок', 'сниппет' , 'brand_rate','snippet_rate', 'url_rate'])
            csv_writer.writerow([ 'brand_names: ' + str(self.brand_names), 'additional_brand_words: ' + str(self.additional_brand_words), 'urls: ' + str(self.urls), 'keys: '+ str(self.keys)])

            return csv_writer
```

it works fine:
[image]

BUt when I try to upload cpde to pythonanywhere.com and host it there - everything brokes and I see strange symbols:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps your browser is not set to display utf-8 or try encoding the file with `utf8-sig` so the file has a BOM and then re-upload to test.

Comment: this is not browser - this is microsoft excel

Comment: How are you running the code on PythonAnywhere?   Are you sure you're using Python 3.x?   The command `python` in bash will launch Python 2.7. you need to use `python3.6` or equivalent to use Python 3.